# Cannot Access Network Share from Windows 10 over VPN

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, windows-explorer

Usually, I connect to a remote server over vpn and access files by typing \192.168.1.1\c$ in the explorer, or use xcopy with the ip and folder as source path.

Now I get the error code 0x80004005 - unknown error from explorer and invalid path from xcopy.

ping to ip adress works. Rdp access also works fine.

Except Windows Updates nothing has been changed to either side (client and server).

How can I fix this? What would be the next thing to analyse along the way?

**update 1:**

`net use * /delete` did not solve the issue

`net use Z: \\192.168.1.1\c$` returns error 53

**update 2:**

Updating to Windows 10 20H2 (19042.685) did not solve the issue

**update 3:**

enabling smb client did not solve the issue

[image]

Comment: Check SMB client log on windows 10 and SMB server log on remote server to see if there are something related. Can you access the share with hostname or FQDN? What's the result? Like: \\FQDN\c$

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Bitdefender Firewall did solve the issue.